# Does saving and logging out of an account reset its progress?

Tags: geometry-dash

I want to make a new account without deleting my current one, so if I save my progress and log out do I lose all progress when logging out?

Answer (score 1):

If you log out from your Geometry Dash account your Geometry Dash App will reset, however your account will not. If you log back in you will get your data back. Make sure to use the accounts "save" option before logging out.